# Cyrillic bibliographic entry using Biblatex and Polyglossia (initials broken)

Tags: biblatex, xetex, polyglossia

I have a problem with either getting the correct font type in the bibliography, or (when enforcing the language setting in the bibliographic entry) getting the author first name processed as it should.

The preferred solution would be to get the `Author = {\textrussian{Белый}, \textrussian{Андрей}},` processed properly in the bibliography part. Currently the name initials is thrown out and the `\` from the `\bibinitperiod` also disappears.

Any suggestions welcome :)

[image: result]

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}                                
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  hyperref=true,
  backend=biber,
  maxbibnames=99,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  maxcitenames=2,
  parentracker=true,
  url=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  eprint=false,
  backref=true,
  }{biblatex}
  \usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Attanasio2010,
  abstract = {This paper provides a critical survey of the large literature on the life cycle model of consumption, both from an empirical and a theoretical point of view. It discusses several approaches that have been taken in the literature to bring the model to the data, their empirical successes and failures. Finally, the paper reviews a number of changes to the standard life cycle model that could help solve the remaining empirical puzzles.},
  author = {Kaminsky, Graciela Laura and Schmukler, Sergio L.},
  journal = {NBER Working Paper},
  month = feb,
  shorttitle = {Consumption and saving},
  title = {{Consumption and saving: models of intertemporal allocation and their implications for public policy}},
  url = {http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract\_id=1558816 http://www.nber.org/papers/w15756},
  volume = {756},
  number = {12},
  year = {2010}
}
@article{Galindo2002,
  author = {Galindo, Arturo and Schiantarelli, Fabio and Weiss, Andrew},
  journal = {American Economic Review},
  month = apr,
  shorttitle = {Does Financial Liberalization Improve the Allocati},
  title = {{Does Financial Liberalization Improve the Allocation of Investment?: Micro Evidence from Developing Countries}},
  url = {http://ideas.repec.org/p/idb/wpaper/4295.html},
  volume = {47},
  number = {2},
  year = {2002}
}
@book{belyj1919a,
  Address = {München},
  Author = {Bjäly, Andrej},
  Publisher = {Georg Müller},
  Title = {Petersburg},
  Year = {1919},
  language = {german},
  hyphenation = {german},
}
@book{belyj1919b,
  Address = {\textgerman{München}},
  Author = {\textgerman{Bjäly}, \textgerman{Andrej}},
  Publisher = {\textgerman{Georg Müller}},
  Title = {{\textgerman{Petersburg}}},
  Year = {1920},
  language = {german},
  hyphenation = {german},
}
@book{belyj1913a,
  Address = {\textrussian{Москва}},
  Author = {\textrussian{Белый}, \textrussian{Андрей}},
  Publisher = {\textrussian{Наука}},
  Title = {\textrussian{Петербург}},
  Year = {1981},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}
@book{belyj1913b,
  Address = {Москва},
  Author = {\textrussian{Белый}, \textrussian{Андрей}},
  Publisher = {Наука},
  Title = {Петербург},
  Year = {1982},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true, 
  citecolor=blue} 

\begin{document}

\textgerman{\cite{belyj1919a}}
\cite{belyj1919b},
\cite{belyj1913b}, 
\textrussian{\cite{belyj1913a}}, 
\cite{Attanasio2010}
\citep{Galindo2002}
(see, for example, \citealp{Attanasio2010})

For \emph{russian} and \emph{german} languages the author first name is not processed as it should\ldots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: one possible solution is to replace 
`Author = {\textrussian{Белый}, \textrussian{Андрей}},` with `Author = {\textrussian{Белый, А.}},`.

But this will be insufficient for managing multiple authors and the distinction between the first and a subsequent quotations in the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forgetting to define a main font; don't use `\text...` in the bibliographic entries. Don't try mixing Latin Modern and Linux Libertine, they're visually incompatible with each other. If you want a Computer Modern style font, use the CMUnicode fonts.

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}                                
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  hyperref=true,
  backend=biber,
  maxbibnames=99,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  maxcitenames=2,
  parentracker=true,
  url=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  eprint=false,
  backref=true,
  ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Attanasio2010,
  abstract = {This paper provides a critical survey of the large literature on the life cycle model of consumption, both from an empirical and a theoretical point of view. It discusses several approaches that have been taken in the literature to bring the model to the data, their empirical successes and failures. Finally, the paper reviews a number of changes to the standard life cycle model that could help solve the remaining empirical puzzles.},
  author = {Kaminsky, Graciela Laura and Schmukler, Sergio L.},
  journal = {NBER Working Paper},
  month = feb,
  shorttitle = {Consumption and saving},
  title = {{Consumption and saving: models of intertemporal allocation and their implications for public policy}},
  url = {http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract\_id=1558816 http://www.nber.org/papers/w15756},
  volume = {756},
  number = {12},
  year = {2010}
}
@article{Galindo2002,
  author = {Galindo, Arturo and Schiantarelli, Fabio and Weiss, Andrew},
  journal = {American Economic Review},
  month = apr,
  shorttitle = {Does Financial Liberalization Improve the Allocati},
  title = {{Does Financial Liberalization Improve the Allocation of Investment?: Micro Evidence from Developing Countries}},
  url = {http://ideas.repec.org/p/idb/wpaper/4295.html},
  volume = {47},
  number = {2},
  year = {2002}
}
@book{belyj1919a,
  Address = {München},
  Author = {Bjäly, Andrej},
  Publisher = {Georg Müller},
  Title = {Petersburg},
  Year = {1919},
  language = {german},
  hyphenation = {german},
}
@book{belyj1919b,
  Address = {München},
  Author = {Bjäly, Andrej},
  Publisher = {Georg Müller},
  Title = {Petersburg},
  Year = {1920},
  language = {german},
  hyphenation = {german},
}
@book{belyj1913a,
  Address = {Москва},
  Author = {Белый, Андрей},
  Publisher = {Наука},
  Title = {Петербург},
  Year = {1981},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}
@book{belyj1913b,
  Address = {Москва},
  Author = {Белый, Андрей},
  Publisher = {Наука},
  Title = {Петербург},
  Year = {1982},
  language = {russian},
  hyphenation = {russian},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true, 
  citecolor=blue} 

\begin{document}

\cite{belyj1919a},
\cite{belyj1919b},
\cite{belyj1913b}, 
\cite{belyj1913a}, 
\cite{Attanasio2010}
\citep{Galindo2002}
(see, for example, \citealp{Attanasio2010})

For \emph{russian} and \emph{german} languages the author first name is not processed as it 
should\ldots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I get after replacing the font declarations with

```
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful and works like charm not only here (in the minimal example) but in my thesis as well :) Thank you!

Comment: hmm, on the other hand CMU looks a lot worse than standard CM. Is it possible to use CMU only for greek and russian (including the bibliography)?

Comment: @VladSkywalker You could try `ucharclasses`, if you want different fonts for different character sets.

Comment: After:  
`\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}  
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic,Scale=MatchUppercase]{CMU Serif}`  


I have added:  
`\usepackage[Latin,Cyrillics]{ucharclasses}  
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\begingroup\cyrillicfont}{\endgroup}  
\setTransitionsForGreek{\begingroup\greekfont}{\endgroup}`  

and that has sorted out most of my problems...  

I shall have a look for a better font, but at least now I have quite valid method to play with it --- thanks again!