# Bibliography alphabetic ordering

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting, sharelatex

Again, I've faced the problem of bibliography sorting with no clue how to deal with it. The issue is in the fact, that the specific requirments for russian papers make me use custom-made style `utf8gost705u.bst`, as it is the only one, that fits the most requirments. However, there is an obligation for bibliography to be ordered in an alphabetical way, starting from cyrillic, which is not followed by thath biblio-style.

So it goes in this way:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
Some text \cite{}.
\bibliographystyle{gutf8gost705u}
\bibliography{name}
\end{document}


@article{Razumova,
title={Исламский Банкинг: Мировой Опыт и Возможности Для России},
author={Разумова, Ирина Анатольевна},
journal={Учебные Записки Международного Банковского Института},
number={11-1},
pages={157-166},   
year={2015},
language="russian",
publisher={Международный Банковский Институт Санкт-Петербург}
}

@book{iqbal2011introduction,
title={An introduction to Islamic finance: Theory and practice},
author={Iqbal, Zamir and Mirakhor, Abbas},
volume={687},
year={2011},
language="English",
publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}

@book{warde2000islamic,
title={Islamic finance in the global economy},
author={Warde, Ibrahim},
year={2011},
language="english",
publisher={Edinburgh University Press}
}

@article{bektax,
title={Исламские налоги как эффективный инструмент решения социально-экономических проблем в местах компактного проживания мусульман в России},
author={Беккин, Р.И},
journal={Проблемы современной экономики},
number={03},
pages={480--490},
year={2009},
language="russian",
publisher={Научно-производственная компания" РОСТ"}
}
```

How to make it ordered alphabetically, from cyrillic to latin letters keeping on using the exact `\bibliographystyle{utf8gost705u}`?

Comment: Did you try with `biblatex-gost`` and `biber`? It's easier to customise biblatex.

Comment: Try [Cyrillic first names problem with natbib and bibtex answer by egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183869/79756).
And, yes, if you are not restricted — switch to `biblatex` with `biber` backend (and `biblatex-gost` package). It is much comfortable to use. And solution to this problem described in russian: http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatexgost/wiki/Home/#_1

Comment: Are you publishing for a journal? Ask the editors for advice.